# Netcat server and intermittent UDP datagram loss

Tags: linux, networking, udp, fedora

The client on `enp4s0 (192.168.0.77)` is sending short text-messages permanently to `192.168.0.1:6060`. The server on `192.168.0.1` listen on `6060` via `nc -ul4 --recv-only 6060`

A ping (`ping -s 1400  192.168.0.77`) from server to client works fine. Wireshark is running on `192.168.0.1 (enp4s0)` and detects that all datagrams are correct. There are no packages missing.

But netcat (as also a simple UDP-server) receives only sporadic on datagrams.

Any Idea what's going wrong?

---

System configuration:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

# ip route
default via 192.168.77.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp4s0 proto static metric 101 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 metric 101 
192.168.77.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.77.25 metric 100 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 

# uname -a
Linux nadhh 5.1.20-300.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 26 15:03:11 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I suspect nc doesn't opean a different process / thread for each incoming datagram, so datagrams arriving when nc is processing a previous one could be lost. As UDP doesn't guarantee delivery of datagrams this would be the expected beheaviour. You can try putting some delay between messages and see if it stops dropping datagrams. Or write an Udp server that opens a separate thread for each connection to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Can you add the server you wrote to the question?

Comment: Good tip, but the gap between a fragment is several seconds. It only takes microseconds to print out the content. I wrote a small udp server. So I could see that the Recvfrom was locked while reading. All packets are discarded before being randomly read again.